# Jquery Table rotate vertically if height is larger then monitor

Tags: jquery, rotation

I am trying to create an animation for a table with jQuery when the height is larger then the resolution then do auto scrolling/rotate/marquee.

But without luck; I have tried with http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html this plugin.

Comment: hello, can you post some code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple example, I hope it will help you 
You'll find a table on the page when the browser window is smaller than 400 pixels the Marquee plugin start.
When the browser window become greater 400 px the Marquee plugin stop

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#marquee{width:200px;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
table,td {border:1px solid black;}
td{width:400px}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--isert link to your marquee plugin i download it from https://gist.github.com/remy/2484402-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="marquee.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('marquee').marquee();
    var lar=$('td').width()
    function addMarquee(){
        var len=$('marquee').length
        if(len===0){
            console.log('si')
            $('table tr td span').wrap('<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="2" width="350"></marquee>')
            }
        }
    function deleteMarquee(){
        var len=$('marquee').length
        if(len>0){
         $('table tr td span').unwrap()
        }
        }   
    $(window).resize( function(){
        var width = $(window).width();
        if(width<400){
            addMarquee()
            }else{
            deleteMarquee() 
            }
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><td><span>START Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet END</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span>START Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet END</span></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I hope that this example will help you